# can not pass queryParams to server

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

i am trying to pass the products queryParams for my product-list page.

my html code (just one option for the example) -

```
<a 
class="linkCategoriesInner__link"
[routerLink]="['/product-list']"
[queryParams]="{ gender: 2, category: 2 }"
>Jackets</a>
```

when i click im directed to `localhost:4200/product-list?gender=2&category=2`

then im getting the queryParams on my product-list component -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        console.log(params);  
      }
    )
```

here i get my queryParams

then im trying to pass it to the server by the following files -

products resolver -

```
class ProductsResolver
  implements
    Resolve<
      Pick<IProductInterface, 'image' | 'title' | 'price' | 'description'>[]
    >
{
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Pick<
  IProductInterface, 'image' | 'title' | 'price' | 'description'>[]
  > {
    console.log(+route.paramMap.get('gender')!)
    return this.productService.getProducts(
      +route.paramMap.get('gender')!,
      +route.paramMap.get('category')!,
      );
  }
}
```

products.service.ts -

```
 public getProducts(
    gender: ProductGender,
    category: ProductCategory
  ): Observable<IProductInterface[]> {
    return this.httpProductService.getProducts(gender, category).pipe(
      catchError((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let errorMessage: string;

        switch (errorResponse.status) {
          case 400:
            errorMessage = 'Getting products failed';
            break;
          default:
            errorMessage = 'An error occurred';
        }

        return throwError(errorMessage);
      }),
      map((response: IGetProductsResponse) => response.data!)
    );
  }
```

http-products.service.ts -

```
 public getProducts(
    gender: ProductGender,
    category: ProductCategory
  ): Observable<IGetProductsResponse> {
    const baseUrl = ENDPOINT;

    return this.http.get<IGetProductsResponse>(
      `${baseUrl + gender}/${category}`
    );
  }
```

and i get 0 in the queryParams in the backend controller.
does anyone know why? thanks.

Comment: can you console.log this ... `${baseUrl + gender}/${category}` ... in http-products.service.ts ... is the value as expected? if this is as expected then the problem must be server side. If the value is not as expected then it must be client side.

Comment: @danday74 the value is not as excepted. what can i do about it? i know its from the client side but i dont know where is the error

Comment: console.log gender and category every step of the journey (every time they are used or set) and tell me when they are not as expected, then we can focus efforts on fixing that

Comment: @danday74 in the resolver i dont get what im expecting. i think i need to pass the data form the component to the resolver and i dont know how